# Find $\lim \limits_{s\to 16} \frac{4-\sqrt{s}}{s-16}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How do you find this limit using algebra?

$$
\lim \limits_{s\to 16} \frac{4-\sqrt{s}}{s-16}
$$

By graphing I get 1/8.

Comment: $\lim \limits_{s\to 16} \frac{4-\sqrt{s}}{s-16}=-\lim \limits_{s\to 16} \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}+4}=-\frac{1}{8}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{4-\sqrt{s}}{s-16} = -\frac{\sqrt{s}-4}{(\sqrt{s}-4)(\sqrt{s}+4)}.$$